# Can't get Python with cx_oracle to connect outbound to Oracle server

Tags: docker, python, network

When I inherently go to make the connection from the python app inside the docker file I get .. I can ping and nslookup from indide the docker container from the terminal....so I'm a bit confused..

> 2023-08-12
> 01:30:45.665974(DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=TCP)(HOST='host.host.host')(PORT=1521))(CONNECT_DATA=(SERVICE_NAME='ADMTST')))DPY-6005:
> cannot connect to database. Connection failed with "[Errno -2] Name
> does not resolve"

Docker File:

```
FROM python:3-alpine

WORKDIR /app
 
COPY requirements.txt .
COPY package.json .
RUN apk add openldap-dev
RUN apk update && apk add python3-dev \
                        gcc \
                        libc-dev \
                        npm

RUN pip install --upgrade pip
RUN pip install --upgrade setuptools
RUN python3 -m pip install -U "Cython<3.0.0"
RUN python3 -m pip install --no-build-isolation "oracledb==1.2.2"

RUN pip install -r requirements.txt

RUN npm install

COPY . .
RUN mv node_modules ./static/
EXPOSE 8000
CMD ["gunicorn","--access-logfile","LOGS/access_logs","--error-logfile","LOGS/error_logs","--certfile","tempSSL/certificate.pem","--keyfile","tempSSL/server.key","--workers","4", "-b", "0.0.0.0:8000", "wsgi:app"]
```

Docker Compose

```
version: '3.8'
services:
  app:
    build: .
    ports:
      - 8000:8000
      - 1521:1521
```

Answer (score 0):

Your problem in this case is very clear..

> 2023-08-12 01:30:45.665974(DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=TCP)(**HOST='host.host.host'**)(PORT=1521))(CONNECT_DATA=(SERVICE_NAME='ADMTST')))DPY-6005: cannot connect to database. Connection failed with **"[Errno -2] Name does not resolve"**

Whatever that code is being called (in python), you're trying to connect to a database called `host.host.host`. That means under the hood something is trying to resolve `host.host.host` to an ip address. There is nothing on your network or in your hosts file that can resolve `host.host.host`.